# How do I position IIFE charts within an HTML page?

Tags: html, lightningchart

The chart isn't showing within the element where I placed the chart's script snippet. Instead it's appearing at the bottom of the page after all HTML elements.

Script is placed here:

```
<body>
   <div1>
       <div2>
           <script>CHART SCRIPT</script>
       </div2>
   </div1>
</body>
```

Yet appears outside the DIV, like:

```
<body>
   <div1>
       <div2>
           <script>CHART SCRIPT</script>
       </div2>
   </div1>
   [CHART DISPLAYING HERE]
</body>
```

Comment: Give an example of your code. We need to know what you are trying in order to help fix it

Comment: @cs641311 edited with code example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on the code inside the script. It may be calling code like this:

```js
document.body.appendChild(element);
```

This adds the chart to the body. If you are able to edit the script code, change it to something like this:

```html
<body>
   <div1>
       <div2 id='chat-holder'>
           <script>
           /* I am guessing that your script creates 
              an element for the chart and will 
              refer to it as chartElement. 
              Change the name if needed */
           var chartHolder = document.getElementById('chart-holder');
           chartHolder.appendChild(chartElement);
           </script>
       </div2>
   </div1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

The location of the script element that invokes LightningChart JS is not tied to the the location of the chart.

If you think about it, this is logical because one script could create multiple charts which could be nice to have in different locations on the web page.

To position your chart on a DIV element of your choosing, specify that DIV when creating the chart:

```
<body>
   <div>
       <div id = 'chart-container'></div>
   </div>
   <script>
       const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY({
           container: document.getElementById('chart-container')
       })
   </script>
</body>
```